# Как удалить все связи в postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin4

Как можно через pgadmin 4 удалить все связи у всех таблиц в схемах? Желательно, чтобы Primary Key не затронуло.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте как [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40755239/drop-foreign-keys-generally-in-postgres)

```
b=# create table a (a int primary key, b int unique);
CREATE TABLE
b=# create table b (a int references a(a), b int references a(b));
CREATE TABLE
b=# do
$$
declare r record;
begin
for r in (select constraint_name from information_schema.table_constraints where table_schema = 'public' and table_name='b') loop
  raise info '%','dropping '||r.constraint_name;
  execute CONCAT('ALTER TABLE "public"."b" DROP CONSTRAINT '||r.constraint_name);
end loop;
end;
$$
;
INFO:  dropping b_a_fkey
INFO:  dropping b_b_fkey
DO
```

Comment: В этом коде мне нужно что-то подогнать под себя? Свои таблицы где-то подставить нужно? У меня 5 таблиц, user, contract, city, house, role.

Comment: Да, просмотрите как возращяют constraints и как их удалять

Comment: В этом я не силён, sql для меня не так близок, спасибо, физически удалю таблицы и пересоздам